# play audio in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

how to create  a customized audio player.like the pic tagged below...in genral if i am to play an audio..i get the default audio player..

[image]

Comment: Customize how, what do you mean?

Comment: You want to "skin" the audio player to look like it does above?  Sort of like there are skins for winamp: http://www.winamp.com/skins

Comment: Are you looking for just one look, or do you need several different skins to change from?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting started with AVAudioPlayer:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

That'll give you the ability to play the audio programmatically -- then you can build the custom controls

Comment: i was able to build an audio player programatically...wat i want is to customize it

Comment: customize how?  I think we need more information to give you the answer you're looking for

Comment: basically i m parsing media url in xml format  from net..below is the code..NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]
        initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [item objectForKey:@"url"]]]; 
 
 [self.itemSummary loadRequest:request];

Comment: Need more code than that -- what are you using for your audio player?  What are you trying to customize?

Comment: i m parsing rss feed containing the media url and loading in web view...which gives me a default audio player and plays the url content when it is run in the simulator...the above is the complete code in my view controller

Comment: @user652878, you know how to code, so post more code, tell us which files you have, what you want to do.

Comment: @user652878 if you want custom controls like the image above, you're going to want to load the audio files in something like AVAudioPlayer, not a web view.  The web view will be a world of hurt to try to customize, as the SDK doesn't really give you access to doing that.  I suppose you could load an HTML5 page and play the audio in it and use HTML5 controls, but that would be different than just loading the audio file in the web view